# How to define a reference for understanding what a link is called?

Tags: jquery

Just starting to learn jQuery.
I have 100 of the same links:

```
<span class="plus col-lg-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+</span>
```

I need to add a link to the unique attribute which I can access through jQuery to read it.

For example: 
I clicking to link, after that i get

```
$('.plus').on('click', function(){
   if($(this).uniq_attribute == "Link name 1") {
      ...
   }
})
```

Comment: Why then put a minus, pass on or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `data-...` attributes like this:

```
$('.plus').on('click', function(){
   if($(this).data('uniq-attribute') == "Link name 1") {
      ...
   }
})
```

And html:

```
<span class="plus col-lg-1" data-uniq-attribute="Link name 1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+</span>
```